# Solve a double summation in R

Tags: r

Is there any way of solving the following sum in R:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You can calculate this without any `for` loops:

```
double_sum <- function(j) {
  sum(sapply(1:j, function(i) sum(1/i:j))^2) / j^2
}
```

And then calculate for each `j`:

```
> sapply(1:50, outer_sum)
 [1] 1.00000000 0.62500000 0.46296296 0.36979167 0.30866667 0.26527778 0.23279883 0.20753348 0.18729669 0.17071032
[11] 0.15686052 0.14511659 0.13502879 0.12626754 0.11858565 0.11179403 0.10574549 0.10032374 0.09543562 0.09100565
[21] 0.08697198 0.08328344 0.07989737 0.07677785 0.07389447 0.07122127 0.06873600 0.06641942 0.06425487 0.06222779
[31] 0.06032545 0.05853663 0.05685142 0.05526106 0.05375773 0.05233445 0.05098496 0.04970367 0.04848551 0.04732591
[41] 0.04622074 0.04516625 0.04415901 0.04319591 0.04227410 0.04139098 0.04054415 0.03973142 0.03895077 0.03820032
```

Or something strange (built upper triangle matrix for coefficient and then sum rows and results):

```
mat_sum <- function(j) {
  d <- outer(rep(1, j), 1:j, FUN="/")
  d[lower.tri(d)] <- 0
  sum(rowSums(d)^2) / j^2
}
```

And benchmarks:

```
> s <- 1:100
> microbenchmark::microbenchmark(for_sum=sapply(s, sumfun), double_sum=sapply(s, double_sum), mat_sum=sapply(s, mat_sum))
Unit: milliseconds
       expr      min        lq      mean    median        uq      max neval
    for_sum 9.601222 10.261159 11.996525 10.774037 11.894962 30.56077   100
 double_sum 6.075801  6.678923  8.787946  7.373223  8.697266 21.37783   100
    mat_sum 7.809572  8.770058 13.766358 10.190758 18.500802 46.18336   100
```

Comment: Manually I checked, the second value of sum (for j=2) is 0.375. There is something wrong with the code.

Comment: In Wolfram Mathematica I'm getting the same result, as in R. The exact value for `j=2` is `5/8`. Check the [Wolfram|Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+for+i+from+1+to+j+(sum+for+k+from+i+to+j+1%2F(k+j))%5E2+for+j+%3D+2).

Comment: Please, recheck your calculations, you took the square of each term, but you need to take the square of the whole inner sum. Here is the result for `j=2`: `(1/2 + 1/4)^2 + (1/4)^2 = 5/8`, and you calculated: `(1/2)^2 + (1/4)^2 + (1/4)^2 = 3/8`.

Answer (score 2):

```
sumfun <- function(j) {
    res <- 0
    for(i in 1:j) {
        temp <- 0
        for(k in i:j) {
            temp <- temp + 1/(k*j)
        }
        res <- res + temp^2
    }
    return(res)
}

sapply(1:50, sumfun)
```

```
[1] 1.00000000 0.62500000 0.46296296 0.36979167 0.30866667 0.26527778 0.23279883 0.20753348 0.18729669 0.17071032 0.15686052
[12] 0.14511659 0.13502879 0.12626754 0.11858565 0.11179403 0.10574549 0.10032374 0.09543562 0.09100565 0.08697198 0.08328344
[23] 0.07989737 0.07677785 0.07389447 0.07122127 0.06873600 0.06641942 0.06425487 0.06222779 0.06032545 0.05853663 0.05685142
[34] 0.05526106 0.05375773 0.05233445 0.05098496 0.04970367 0.04848551 0.04732591 0.04622074 0.04516625 0.04415901 0.04319591
[45] 0.04227410 0.04139098 0.04054415 0.03973142 0.03895077 0.03820032
```

Comment: Manually I checked, the second value of sum (for j=2) is 0.375. There is something wrong with the code.

Comment: Check your work. The double sum for J=2 is (1/2 + 1/4)^2 + 1/4^2 = 10/16 = 0.625.

Comment: sure, but  using  `*apply` is just hiding the sum.  What I'd like to see is the conceptual equivalent of  `sum(over_x , sum(over_y , function(x,y))` so that fully compiled `sum` - like function can be used.

Comment: The function returns X_j.  sapply is just doing the "forall j = 1 to 50" part.  Go crazy and throw in another loop if you want the function to also handle the "forall" part :)